# update document with _id elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried to update a document with `_id`.

```
POST http://example.org/testrest/_update/X3flr2oB9Don9XlKX05E
```

This is a part of doc.:

```
"hits": [
        {
            "_index": "testrest",
            "_type": "testrest",
            "_id": "X3flr2oB9Don9XlKX05E",
            "_score": 0,
            "_source": {
                "price_diff_per_sys": "199.8999",
                "specs": "",
                "gtin_match": "0",
                "human_verdict": "Awaiting",
```

And here's the request body:

```
{
  "doc": { 
    "human_verdict": "Match"
  }
}
```

But then I get this error:

```
{
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
        {
            "type": "invalid_type_name_exception",
            "reason": "Document mapping type name can't start with '_', found: [_update]"
        }
    ],
    "type": "invalid_type_name_exception",
    "reason": "Document mapping type name can't start with '_', found: [_update]"
},
"status": 400
```

}

How can I update document with `_id`?

Comment: which es version you are usinh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL is not malformed and the request body needs to be valid JSON, like this:

```
POST http://example.org/testrest/testrest/X3flr2oB9Don9XlKX05E/_update
{
  "doc": { 
    "human_verdict": "Match"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message clearly saying that you passed the wrong `_type` name which is `_update` in your case, as it says in the error message, in short it can't start with `_`. change it to something else and it should work.

> reason": "Document mapping type name can't start with '_', found:
>   [_update]"

POST http://example.org/testrest/testrest/X3flr2oB9Don9XlKX05E/_update  should work , as I noticed in your payload both indexname and type are same.

```
"_index": "testrest",
 "_type": "testrest",
```

Comment: He still needs to hit the `_update` endpoint at the end of the URL